# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT and the Javascript library

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm running a batch Geocode from JavaScript using the Google Maps JS library  (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

Inevitably I'm getting an intermittent OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response, so I'm looking at the best algorithm to use to ensure maximum throughput. I've read the "10/sec" and the "wait 2s then try again" from the docs.

Here's the question...

**Looking at the network monitor in the dev console, it seems that the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT failures are NOT coming from the server. All of the requests that get through to the server are being resolved correctly. So, is the Google JS library doing its own throttling and returning that OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, and if so, what algorithm is it using to throttle?**

I ask because the throttling I'm seeing doesn't appear to make any sense so I'm considering bypassing the library and using my own server API calls.

Comment: So the library returns OVER_QUERY_LIMIT despite happily sending the request to Google? that doesn't sound correct.  Have you looked at the source for that string?

Comment: Not quite. If I send (say) 10 requests to the library, I get 9 OVER_QUERY_LIMIT failures and 1 successful geocode. When I look at the network stats, I see only the 1 successful call to the Google REST API.

Comment: If I look in http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyATdE6hfyRCmxxxxxx the "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" string appears several times.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your code, you should be able to get approximately 10 results (certainly more than one).  Please either search one of the other answers here dealing with this or provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I don't have an issue! I have a simple question - Is the JS library throttling? The pattern I'm seeing is a progressively higher proportion of my Geolocates fails OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. If I wait 20 minutes and repeat, I still get a higher number of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT failures than I would expect. However, IF I RELOAD THE BROWSER, I get high throughput with few failures. So all the evidence points to the JS library keeping count and doing its own throttling. If you know the answer, please share. If not, just say so.

Comment: Yes, it's throttling....but don't ask me about the algorithm

Comment: @Dr.Molle many thanks. I'll add a bounty tomorrow to see if anybody has any more details on the algorithm that is used. My testing shows it to be pretty brutal, eg after a few hundred geolocates it drops to one success every 20-30 seconds. I'm advising my customer to go away and rethink, but you know what customers are like :-(

Comment: The problem may be that this probably would violate the TOS(10.2.f): ***You will not Reverse engineer or attempt to extract the source code from any Google API***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing, it seems that google does throttle requests in client side.

I've set an interval at every 10ms to get directions between 2 points, here is the output:

```
VM5503:1 [Object, "OK", 1449067457886]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067457888]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067457895]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067457904]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067457914]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067457924]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067457934]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067457944]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067457954]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067457964]
 .............
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067458855]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067458864]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067458876]
VM5503:1 [null, "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT", 1449067458898]
VM5503:1 [Object, "OK", 1449067458903]
```

As you can see only first one and last one is successful here and time difference is: 1017ms.
Only 2 out of these requests actually hit google servers.

I did the same procedure for geocoding service - conclusion is the same, just time between successful geocoding is around 2000-2250ms. On the other hand, there was no constraints for first 5 requests (this seems to be reset after 'some' time, maybe 10s).

Lastly I couldn't find anything about this in docs, except the meaning 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' - which is self explanatory - quota limit. Therefore behavior I described above cannot be trusted to last long.

EDIT:
Timing seems to be consistent:
[image]

Maybe your service/website caught google's attention for more brutal throttling  :)

Comment: Your testing seems to confirm my own. The throttling gets progressively more brutal as the numbers go up. I do wish this stuff was documented as I have no desire to transgress acceptable use policy. Thx fit the research.

Answer (score 0):

Update for latest usage of Google Maps Platform as of July 16, 2018.  Please see the Quota section in the documentation for "New Query per Second (QPS) limits and usage caps at [Quota](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/product-changes/#quota.).  This gives a table for the usage caps for each of the different APIs which does apply to the JavaScript Maps API.  So for instance I am using elevation in my project and I need to make sure I don't query for more than 100 in a second.  It appears that daily limits/caps are not longer a limiting factor.  Related and likely also of interest is pricing:  See [Pricing for Maps, Routes, and Places](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/).